# How can I make mybatis require a transaction?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

In my project I am using Spring and mybatis, with mybatis-spring gluing them together. I am using Spring's declarative @Transactional annotations around my service layers, which call to the mybatis mappers.

I would prefer that NONE of my mapper methods can be called without an active transaction. Instead, they quietly run in a transactionless context (or else they are starting a new transaction).

Is there a way to disable this behavior and make it act more like a MANDATORY propagation level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to create custom `TransactionFactory` which will check if there is active transaction and throw exception otherwise.

```
class MandatoryTransactionSpringManagedTransactionFactory extends SpringManagedTransactionFactory {
     public Transaction newTransaction(DataSource dataSource, TransactionIsolationLevel level, boolean autoCommit) {
         if (!TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
              throw new IllegalTransactionStateException(
                "No existing transaction found during mapper invocation");
         }
         return super.newTransaction(dataSource);
```

}
    }

It should be used to configure `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a hook where I could put some logic, I just wasn't able to find it. By chance I also discovered that annotating my mapper interfaces each with @Tranactional did the trick, but your solution ensures I don't forget to do that.